# Codes consisting of one codeword are perfect.

Tags: coding-theory

the text I am reading makes the statement that the trivial codes are perfect, including when $C$ is the entire space, and when $C$ consists of exactly one codeword. It provides no proof of these, so I was doing them on my own.

I was able to find how to show when $C$ was the entire space, but I am having some issues when $C$ consists of just one codeword. I have been trying to expand:

$\sum_{i=0}^n{{n}\choose{i}}(q-1)^i$ to show that it equals $q^n$, which would result in:

${{q^n}\over{q^n}}=1$

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant (updating the original post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=q-1$, so that $x+1=q$. Then by the binomial theorem

$$q^n=(x+1)^n=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}ix^i1^{n-i}=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}i(q-1)^i\;.$$

Comment: Hello Brian!!! Could I ask you something about Coding Theory?

Comment: @Evinda: You can ask, but I probably won’t be able to answer: that’s an area about which I know very little.

Comment: Let b be a root of y^2+y+1 in F_2[y] and C a linear code over F_4 with the following generator matrix: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RXX5w.png $$$$
I want to find a non-zero vector of the code with minimum weight.
 I have found that the Hamming-distance is 3.
How can we find a word of the code with weight 3?

Comment: @Evinda: As I feared, that’s not something that I could answer without doing a *lot* of reading first. I suggest making a new question of it in hopes of catching the eye of someone more familiar with the subject.

Comment: Ok, I will... Thanks for answering...

Comment: @Evinda: You’re welcome; sorry I couldn’t be of more help.